# How to search/replace without appending search history?

Tags: search, command-history

In a `BufWritePre` to remove trailing spaces, my function uses a search/replace for `\s\+$` over the current buffer. So after saving any buffer, this weird entry `\s\+$` shows up in my search history. Is there a way to search-and-do-not-append-history? Or can a search history entry be automatically deleted (for example, the most recent entry)?

Comment: do you have a plugin for removing trailing whitespace?

Comment: It's in my `.vimrc` (which I figured out about 3 seconds after posting), so I changed the question, since it is still a problem.

Comment: `:h :keeppatterns`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt thanks, that works. So I tried googling for something like this, and found absolutely nothing related. Is there a better way to find out about features in vim? There's no way I can read about them all because it would take a year, and by then I would forget what I read.

Comment: This may not be the answer you want to hear but learning how to do effective google searching will get you quite far. I found `keeppatterns` on my first google search and it's the top result. The search term: "vim don't overwrite search history". Top result: [Vim search without overwriting "/ register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52067483) (In this case the search term was quite straightforward, TBH. What did you look for, if you don't mind saying?)

Comment: I should note that my first destination is always Vim's help. Go to `:h usr_02.txt` and read section 02.8 on. There are many "tricks" for effectively searching Vim's help. (In cases where you're less sure of what to look for Google is probably a better first stop.)

Comment: @BLayer I searched mainly for "vim search exclude history". The idea of "exclude" is a no-go, although it is perfectly correct. Google often gets very confused by punctuation, so I try to avoid apostrophes and such things (for example, searching for a publication citation with periods in the author names will often return nothing, but after removing the periods, it returns 100 links to the paper).

Comment: Apostrophes in simple english language contractions (e.g. `don't`) are unlikely to cause problems. Also, I've found over the years that the search engine has become much more adept at handling natural language than it used to . I probably would have done something like your search five years ago but now that approach often just ends up outsmarting yourself. ;) Put the key word or a couple of them at the front and then a natural language phrase. Surround the phrase with double quotes if it's literal and the whole thing is required. (Disclaimer: of course, YMMV!)

Comment: (cont.) Despite the confidence with which I wrote the preceding I won't claim that I get everything on the first try! Pull out the thesaurus ;) and swap in synonyms for some of the more significant words and try again. And if this is all obvious to you don't take offense, I'm just trying to be thorough. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have an autocommand that is searching for trailing whitespace on save?  That is what `\s\+$` is searching for.

Comment: yes, that was it, and I changed the question accordingly.